# Loads of JComponets, and does it really matter? Java

Tags: java, arrays, jbutton

So its about my first time working in a project this far and im getting a little paranoid about the memory usage...

I want to make a GUI in which in my head, i need about 237 small buttons displayed, just for the sake of user simplicity and visual feedback of what he/she is doing... i guess all i want is a clickable grid that fills spaces depending on weather or not the space is available. no big deal as i would just get the button ActionCommand;

I'm working on a relatively new computer with 12GB Ram, but i need to run the program on a 2GB Ram computer. Do you think there is going to be a problem? and if so im open to suggestions :) thanks in advance.

Comment: 237 user controls is probably a mistake, period.  Best to try something else.  A single component that can determine where (x,y) it was clicked?  Think first, code second.

Comment: If you want to use a grid, then think about using a [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) instead.

Comment: @markspace i agree, however i dont have the time nor the permission to use libraries other than java alone. And i did think of it before, but again im looking for the simplest way. After it is clicked on (x,y) then what? i'd need to change an image or some smaller container to display feedback.

Comment: Are these buttons across multiple panels? You definitely should not have 237 buttons on one panel. If you have many panels, you could implement a cache system, which will de-reference items that haven't been used for a while (or based off your own system). That'll ensure only the buttons that will be used often are taking up memory. You only need to do this if you find yourself having memory constraints. Does your app work within the memory constraints? If not, cache

Comment: Unless a button does not take more than 8 MB of RAM, you won't have a problem with memory. The problems lie somewhere else, as already pointed out.